# Why dp is looking different on 2 devices with same screen density?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, screen, dpi

As far as I know, dp is used to calculate how many pixels are needed to occupy the same space in different screen densities. The following image describes this:

[image]

According to the above information, for example if I have a ConstraintLayout and I am using Top and Bottom margin in an element of the ConstraintLayout (Imagine that Top and Bottom margin is 10dp). If now I test the app in two devices with the same screen density, why the margin is looking different in both devices although the screen density is the same? Shouldn't they have exactly the same px margin according to the definition of dp? Why the margin is looking different in 2 devices that have the same screen density?

Edit of the example:

I am using `app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"` in an AppCompatTextView to resize it according to its space (the AppCompatTextView has width and height = 0dp to fill completely respecting its constraints). So to resize it I am using Top and Bottom margin so that if the margin is higher the text is smaller as it will have less space to fill. As you can see in the following images, I am using 2 devices with same screen density but the text is looking different although the same margin should be applied:

1st device:
[image]

2nd device:
[image]

Comment: Can you post the images of the devices?

Comment: You need to provide more details.
(The pictures are not enough to go on) 
Note: margins are outside of the View. We cannot tell the View Bounds in that picture.
Ideally make a basic ConstraintLayout Layout and a TestView with a background Color.
Provide the XML and screen shots of the two screens with the Layout.

Comment: Adding to what @hoford said, I see that the images are taken from a camera. Instead, take a screenshot and send that